# passing data from uiview to tabview

Tags: tabview

I have a variable 'userID' that is getting populated after validating through a parser. Now when I will press the login button, the next view will be a tabView (Consisting of 5 screens). Now I want this userID to be fixed for UILabel in all tabViews. How to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can store it into NSUserDefaults using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:userID forKey:@"USERID"];
```

and you can get its value anywhere using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"USERID"]]
```